# Expose/Register C++ List of Structure (...of Structures) to QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml, signals-slots

Example code:

```
struct content{
    int id;
    QString body;
};

struct column{
    int id;
    QString name;
    QVector<content> contents;
};

struct row{
    QVector<column> columns;
};

struct page{
    QVector<row> rows;
};
```

I have a C++ class with private member:

```
QVector<page> book;
```

Which is basically a collection of pages, where any page is a collection of rows, where any row is a collection of columns, and finally any column is a collection of contents.

How can I access from qml 'book'? I mean THE SPECIFIC collection of structures (of structures) computed in C++ after it is ready?
I am looking for someway to share it or to pass its features to qml...

I am not sure the Q_PROPERTY(QVector book ...) etc is a good way, as I am not shure if QML does know what a QVector is and what struct page is...

Comment: Is it related to javascript or is it just a typo? Sounds like javascript is far away from there

Comment: Javascript is used in qml, so it may be helpful, as this post is a question for discuss the most proper way... anyway as the javascript tag disturbs you that much I have accepted your edit...

Comment: I didn't suggest any edit but whatever.. ;) that's why I've asked.

Comment: @briosheje we may discuss of a typo, maybe it's even better. I am just looking for a way to easily access the already-computed fields of this collection!!

Comment: You should make your `struct` `Q_OBJECT` or `Q_GADGET`. Then register them with the meta system. You can use e.g. a `QVariantList` to expose them to QML.

Comment: @derM should I make every struct Q_OBJECT? Will it change the procedure c++ to add components? With "procedure" I mean the usual .at(int) and .append(element) methods

Comment: If you don't use Q_OBJECT or Q_GADGET I don't know of any way how you could use those objects in QML in the end. QVariantList is simply a QList<QVariant> so you need to wrap all objects in a QVariant to add stuff.

Comment: @derM could you link me some example or procedure for doing it? And also: does making every structure `Q_OBJECT` change the way elements are added to the structure?

Comment: You should consider a model representation.

Comment: @dtech could you explain better what you mean? Maybe with some link or some examples from you?

Comment: See `QAbstractListModel` - you can implement it as a wrapper around any list of objects to present to QML as a model to feed various of its views, repeaters and so on...